# Find all functions such that $f(x^2+y)=xf(x)+f(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

> Find all functions (over real numbers) such that
>   $$f(x^2+y)=xf(x)+f(y).$$

**My idea**: Put $x=1$. Therefore the given equation becomes $f(y+1)=f(y)+f(1)$. It is in the Cauchy's first form, so we get $f(x)=cx$. It also satisfies that given functional equation.

Is my answer correct?? If not then what is the complete solution?? Please help me!

Comment: That's not in Cauchy's form.

Comment: @Alex Francisco $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is a Cauchy form! And its solution is $f(x)=cx$

Comment: Where can one read about these Cauchy forms?

Comment: What you derived is $f(y+1)=f(y)+f(1)$.

Comment: No, you are not right. If $g$ is a function of period $1$ with $g(0)=0,$  then $f(x)=g(x) +cx$ satisfies $f(x+1)=f(x)+f(1).$

Comment: Is there any statement of continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof that $f$ does satisfy Cauchy's functional equation.  For now, I do not have a complete answer, unless some sort of continuity conditions is given.

Let $P(x,y)$ denote the condition that $f\left(x^2+y\right)=x\,f(x)+f(y)$.  Then, $P(1,0)$ implies that $f(0)=0$.  Now, $P(x,0)$ implies that $$f\left(x^2\right)=x\,f(x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  This shows that $$f\left(x^2+y\right)=f\left(x^2\right)+f(y)$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  Next, $P\left(x,-x^2\right)$ leads to $f\left(-x^2\right)=-f\left(x^2\right)$, and consequently, $$f(-x)=-f(x)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  From this, it can be easily shown that $f$ satisfies Cauchy's functional equation.

Per [Mohsen shahriari](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/229831/mohsen-shahriari)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821321/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y-xfxfy/2821434#comment8044639_2821434) below, knowing that $f$ satisfies Cauchy's functional equation implies that $f(x)=f(1)\,x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Here is a paraphrase of the comment in case it is deleted.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Note that
$$(x+1)\,f(x+1)=(x+1)\,\big(f(x)+f(1)\big)=(x+1)\,f(x)+(x+1)\,f(1)\,,\tag{1}$$
that
$$\begin{align}(x+1)\,f(x+1)&=f\big((x+1)^2\big)=f\big(x^2+(2x+1)\big)\\&=x\,f(x)+f(2x+1)=x\,f(x)+2\,f(x)+f(1)\\&=(x+2)\,f(x)+f(1)\,.\tag{2}\end{align}$$
From (1) and (2),
$$(x+1)\,f(x)+(x+1)\,f(1)=(x+2)\,f(x)+f(1)\,,$$
whence
$$f(x)=x\,f(1)\,.$$

Comment: $$ ( x + 1 ) f ( x ) + ( x + 1 ) f ( 1 ) = ( x + 1 ) f ( x + 1 ) = f \left( ( x + 1 ) ^ 2 \right) \\
= f \left( x ^ 2 + 2 x + 1 \right) = f \left( x ^ 2 \right) + f ( 2 x ) + f ( 1 ) = ( x + 2 ) f ( x ) + f ( 1 ) $$
and thus $ f ( x ) = f ( 1 ) x $.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f \in C$ and arranging as

$$
\frac{f(y+x^2)-f(y)}{x^2}=\frac{f(x)}{x} = \phi(x)
$$

So

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(y+x^2)-f(y)}{x^2}=\phi(0)
$$

which is independent of $y$ hence $f(x) = C_0 x$

Comment: It's enough to assume $f$ is continuous. Then your argument shows that the derivative exists and is constant.

Comment: Yes. I left an exponent in excess at $C$. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \phi(x)$ exists?

Comment: Because this implies on that the first limit does not exists for any $y$.