# Find all functions over reals such that $f(t^2+u)=tf(t)+f(u)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(t^2+u)=tf(t)+f(u)$$

My progress

Setting $(x,y)$ in the equation where $x,y \geq0$. We have$$f(x+y)=\sqrt{x}f(\sqrt{x})+f(y).\tag{1}$$
Now, setting $(y,x)$ in the equation we have, $$f(y+x)=\sqrt{y}f(\sqrt{y})+f(x). \tag{2}
$$Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ we get $$f(x)-\sqrt{x}f(\sqrt{x})=f(y)-\sqrt{y}f(\sqrt{y})$$
This implies that $f(x)-\sqrt{x}f(\sqrt{x})$ is constant for all $x \geq 0$ or $f(x)=\sqrt{x}f(\sqrt{x})+c$ for some constant $c$. Combining this fact with $(1)$ the functional equation can be reduced to $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+c.\tag{3}$$ for $x,y \geq 0.$ The solution to this Cauchy's functional equation can be found to $f(x)=kx+c(x-1)$ where $k$ is $f(1)$. Now putting $(1,0)$ in the original functional equation we get $$f(1)=f(1)+f(0)$$This implies $f(0)=0$ and the solution to this functional equation is $f(x)=kx$ for all non-negative reals.

Now my question is: how do we extend this to negative reals? (Any hints shall be appreciated.)

Comment: Let me know if anything [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636093/how-can-i-solve-ft2u-tftfu?noredirect=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821321/find-all-functions-such-that-fx2y-xfxfy?noredirect=1) answers your question. The extension is provided by the fact that $f$ can be shown to be odd, which is covered in a few answers. Marking this as a duplicate will make it a useful reference point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u <0$ there exist $t>0$ such that $t^{2}+u >0$. So $f(u)=f(t^{2}+u)-tf(t)=k(t^{2}+u)-kt^{2}=ku$.